# How can I get a better error message if a required attribute is not supplied in Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

I'm brand new to Moose.  Up until today our environments have been on Perl 5.8.2 which would not support Moose.

I'm working through some examples, and I thought that the "required => 1" setting on an attribute would be handy, however when I try using that option, the error message that is returned is not really usable.

Here's an example:

cat.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{
    package Cat;
    use Moose;
    use Modern::Perl;

    has 'name' => (
        is => 'ro',
        required => 1,
    );
    sub meow {
        my $self = shift;
        say 'Meow!';
    }
}

use Modern::Perl;

my $alarm = Cat->new();
$alarm->meow();
$alarm->meow();
$alarm->meow();
```

When I run it:

```
Attribute (name) is required at /app/perl5/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/aix-thread-multi-64all/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 581
        Class::MOP::Class::_construct_instance('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x110ac1a00)', 'HASH(0x110c3b3c0)') called at /app/perl5/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/aix-thread-multi-64all/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 554
        Class::MOP::Class::new_object('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x110ac1a00)', 'HASH(0x110c3b3c0)') called at /app/perl5/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/aix-thread-multi-64all/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 258
        Moose::Meta::Class::new_object('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x110ac1a00)', 'HASH(0x110c3b3c0)') called at /app/perl5/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/aix-thread-multi-64all/Moose/Object.pm line 28
        Moose::Object::new('Cat') called at cat.pl line 20
```

If one of our non-perl operators see an error message like that, they will probably freak out.  I'm afraid they will not realize that all 5 lines in the error message are actually a part of the same error.

Is there a way to get a nice error message if a required attribute is not supplied?

Something like croak, I can imagine a message like this:

```
Attribute (name) is required at cat.pl line 20
```

Again, I'm new to Moose so this may be an easy setting that I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution to my requirement, but I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

And, as @Tanktalus points out, there is value to having a detailed error message.

For the purposes of my question, the [MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors) extension seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{
    package Cat;
    use Moose;
    use MooseX::Constructor::AllErrors;
    use Modern::Perl;

    has 'name' => (
        is => 'ro',
        required => 1,
    );
    sub meow {
        my $self = shift;
        say 'Meow!';
    } 
}

use Modern::Perl;

my $alarm = Cat->new(); 
$alarm->meow(); 
$alarm->meow(); 
$alarm->meow();
```

On running, I get:

```
Attribute (name) is required at cat.pl line 21
```

Which is what I was thinking.

Since I am not familiar at all with Moose, is this extension okay to use, or will it "muffle" all of the error messages?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the long error message - because if I'm missing a required parameter, I **want** my non-perl users to freak out: I obviously missed something in development, unit-test, and system test if it gets all the way to a user with this type of message.

Mind you, I also leave fatal warnings turned on when I go to production.  I prefer my failures to be spectacular so that I can't accidentally ignore them.

Comment: That's a good point, but to someone who is not familiar with Perl, I think `Attribute (name) is required at cat.pl line 20` is a lot more helpful to someone trying to diagnose a problem then the huge version of the message.  Probably a preference difference - I do see your point though.

Answer (score -1):

Since "name" is required, what you need to do is populate this attribute from the constructor. Like this:

```
my $alarm = Cat->new({'name' => 'Sylvester'});
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: That doesn't fix my "problem" - my question centers around the error message that appears when they _don't_ supply a 'name'.